# Transfering the content of a variable to file in SQL Server 2k5

Tags: sql-server-2005

How do we transfer the content of a string variable to a file on a SP? I need to do these:

1. Create an empty text file from an SP
2. Push the content of a variable (whose len is 25487) to the newly created file

The variable size is Varchar(Max), and this is the code I am trying to make work (but it ain't [Sad] ) ---

Declare @cmd sysname
Declare @ReqContent Varchar(max)

SET @cmd = 'echo ' + @ReqContent + ' > C:\DD4TRD.txt'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd ,NO_OUTPUT

Thanks,
Sayan

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this sproc](http://www.simple-talk.com/code/WorkingWithFiles/spWriteStringTofile.txt) from [Reading and Writing Files in SQL Server using T-SQL](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/).